# Iterating over plans returned by Stripe's PHP API wrapper

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

As far as I can see, there was a way to iterate over collections returned by official Stripe PHP library like this:

```
foreach (\Stripe\Plan::all() as $plan) {
    print("$plan->id ($plan->interval)\n");
}
```

But that does not work any more (I'm on PHP7 and use [stripe/stripe-php](https://packagist.org/packages/stripe/stripe-php) v3.9.2). I have to run it like this:

```
foreach (\Stripe\Plan::all()->__toArray()['data'] as $plan) {
    print("$plan->id ($plan->interval)\n");
}
```

Did anyone else noticed this problem? What changed? While I know how to make it work, it just does not look right.

Comment: file an issue on the github repo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this never worked. `::all()` calls return a `Collection` object (or a `Stripe_List` object in 1.x versions) that is not directly iterable.

The proper syntax to iterate over the results of a call to `::all()` is:

```
foreach (\Stripe\Plan::all()->data as $plan) {
    // Do something with $plan
}
```

With the newer versions (>= 3.9.0), you can use the auto-paging feature:

```
foreach (\Stripe\Plan::all()->autoPagingIterator() as $plan) {
    // Do something with $plan
}
```

This will let you iterate over the entire list of plans automatically. The bindings will take care of issuing all the requests with [pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pagination) parameters in the background for you.